# Share product image in whatsapp

Tags: magento-1.9

I developed whats-app share extension.
and I want to share image can any one help me how to share product image to whats-app.

```
<?php

include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

Mage::app(); // Mage_Core_Model_App

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));


$productId = '100';
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->load($productId);
?>



 <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo ($product->getName()); ?>" />
 <meta property="og:type" content="product" />
 <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(200,200);?>" />
 <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(($product->getShortDescription())); ?>" />
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(); ?>" />
 <body>
 <div>

 <a href='<?php echo 'whatsapp://send?text=https://magecomp.com/dev/magento-2-custom-stock-status.html%0A%0A'; ?>' > 
    hello
 </a>

 </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: You can use open graph meta tag in your product page

Comment: can you give me code

Answer (score 1):

**Use open graph meta tag**

Just copy and paste below codes in head.phtml file in our template file.

```
<?php if(Mage::registry('current_product')): ?>
 <?php $product = Mage::registry('current_product'); ?>
 <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo ($product->getName()); ?>" />
 <meta property="og:type" content="product" />
 <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(200,200);?>" />
 <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo Mage::registry('product')->getProductUrl(); ?>" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(($product->getShortDescription())); ?>" />
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(); ?>" />
 <?php endif; ?>
```

More [Info](http://sarathlal.com/add-open-graph-meta-tags-in-magento/)

Comment: You can refer extension https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/socialshare-open-graph.html

Comment: what code i do for share product image to whatsapp

Comment: i have button in category page to share product

Comment: Basically share any media to whatsapp from website is not possible so you can use meta tag. so when you share your product page link it will show the Image of product with it @jigsparmar

Comment: ok wait i check

Comment: i edit my question you just check im not able to send product image onyl send product url

Comment: find updated answer @jigsparmar put given code in header template the try to share product url ( Will work not display image for localhost)

Comment: i use updated answer but nothis will happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56149/discussion-between-jigs-parmar-and-gopal-patel).

Comment: @GopalPatel How can i send my EventObserver log message by whatsapp message?